# Unable to start netatalk service

Tags: debian

I have an Ubuntu 16 Server at my home, everything running smoothly even installed webmin to ease my work with some configurations but now I want to install a timemachine server on it and seems that I'm stuck on restarting the netatalk service.

It gives me the following error

> Failed to start netatalk.service: Unit netatalk.service is masked.

The first thing I've tried was uninstall the netatalk package a reinstall it, then I tried disable the service and refresh the daemon it didn't work either.

The tutorial that I followed is this one

[Use Ubuntu network share for Apple TimeMachine backups?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516134/use-ubuntu-network-share-for-apple-timemachine-backups)

I want to avoid reseting my system and I no longer can figure out what to do.

Don't know if this helps, but here's the status output

> pedro@HITMAN-SERVER:~$ sudo service netatalk status
>
> ● netatalk.service
>
> Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
>
> Active: inactive (dead)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

==== EDIT ====

After George idea I was able to remove the symlink giving this status

> pedro@HITMAN-SERVER:/lib/systemd/system$ sudo systemctl status netatalk
>
> ● netatalk.service
>
> Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
>
> Active: inactive (dead)

There should be a file called netatalk.service in the folder /lib/systemd/system that by removing said file the service should disappear from the system but I can not find the file and I believe that because the service is still being detected the `apt-get install netatalk` does not configure the service correctly

I've placed a search on my system for the netatalk.service and removed (created backup) of said files and rebooted the computer... The service still appears on systemctl

Comment: Please try `sudo unmask netatalk`, then do `systemctl status netatalk` and see if it removes the link to `/dev/null`

Comment: Partially solved. it removed the mask but the service is still there. I had to make a change in the first command though it is sudo systemctl unmask netatalk.

Comment: Yes that change was in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the George's help and a bit more of search I was able to properly run netatalk.

The correct steps that I took to fix the problem are the following

As George said

`sudo systemctl unmask netatalk`

This will unmasked the /dev/null of the service.

Then I just followed the installation guide bellow instead of using the apt-get command

http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Install_Netatalk_3.1.11_on_Ubuntu_16.04_Xenial

hope this helps other people with similar problems